# How to paginate a html table in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, pagination

i have a html table in which print a query, but the query have a +100 records and it is not clear to me how to paginate it, I have never done a pagination and everything I find with LWC asks me for datatable. The things that are not clear to me, such as the functionality of changing the page and showing new records. The only thing I have done is some lightning buttons to do previous and next and a table that paints data using a for:each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paginating with `lightning-datatable` is just setting the table's data property to the current "view".

I've demonstrated this [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/88mc3Gx8E4OZNksS14kZ/src/app.css?p=stories).

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  // All existing rows
  allData = []
  // All selected Id values
  allSelectedRows = new Set()
  // Current page index
  pageNumber = 0
  // Current page data rows
  pageData = []
  // Current page selected Id values
  selectedRows = []
  // Column display
  columns = [
    { fieldName: "name" }
  ]
  connectedCallback() {
    // Initialize 1k rows
    this.allData = [...new Array(1000).keys()].map((v,i) => ({id:i, name:v}))
    this.updatePage()
  }
  // Just for demo purposes
  get selectedIds() {
    return [...this.allSelectedRows].join(',')
  }
  // Set current page state
  updatePage() {
    this.pageData = this.allData.slice(this.pageNumber*10, this.pageNumber*10+10)
    this.selectedRows = this.pageData.map(row => row.id).filter(pageId => this.allSelectedRows.has(pageId))
  }
  // Back a page
  previous() {
    this.pageNumber = Math.max(0, this.pageNumber - 1)
    this.updatePage()
  }
  // Back to the beginning
  first() {
    this.pageNumber = 0;
    this.updatePage()
  }
  // Forward a page
  next() {
    this.pageNumber = Math.min(Math.floor((this.allData.length-9)/10), this.pageNumber + 1)
    this.updatePage()
  }
  // Forward to the end
  last() {
    this.pageNumber = Math.floor((this.allData.length-9)/10)
    this.updatePage()
  }
  selectRow(event) {
    // Id values for current page
    const pageIds = this.pageData.map(row => row.id)
    // Id values that are now selected on current page
    const selectedIds = new Set(event.detail.selectedRows.map(row => row.id))
    // Deselect all page id values from global Set
    pageIds.forEach(pageId => this.allSelectedRows.delete(pageId))
    // And add in this page's selected values
    selectedIds.forEach(pageId => this.allSelectedRows.add(pageId))
    this.updatePage()
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable selected-rows={selectedRows} data={pageData} columns={columns} key-field="id"
        onrowselection={selectRow}>
    </lightning-datatable>
    <lightning-button-group>
        <lightning-button label="&#x00AB;" onclick={first}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="&lt;" onclick={previous}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="&gt;" onclick={next}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="&#x00BB;" onclick={last}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-button-group>
    Values: {selectedIds}
</template>
```